# How to override or ignore library consumerProguardFiles

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Im using a library that uses `includedescriptorclasses` on their `consumerProguardFiles` but it breaks my build because I use the new shrinker.

Is there any way to replace or ignore the proguard files from a library that uses `consumerProguardFiles`?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve it?